# Options for additional functionality via IOS In-App purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

A bit confused on whether IAP (non-consumable) to extend functionality of application:

1. Just unlocks pre-coded functionality
2. Provides a way to dynamically extend app with new functionality

Any help, guidance, best-practices welcome!

Thanks in advance
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both, depending on what the non-consumable is. If's it's media files, then you can have your app download it. Typically if you are selling code that adds functionality, developers tend to pre-code it and when the purchase occurs, add a flag in `NSUserDefaults` to unlock it. It's much simpler.

Comment: is there even a way to package the code with the purchase and integrate it when purchased? Apple seems to be policy laden when it comes to dynamic libraries.

Comment: If you're talking about letting your app download a library from some server at the time of purchase and push that into your runtime, I highly doubt Apple would be cool with that.

Comment: I accepted the answer. The purest in me prefers a more dynamic capability as I can't see into the future but I have a framework which can be extended. Oh well, more code... <grin>

Comment: mprivat I'm thinking of making my app(Small Strategy Game) to download new levels (Just replacing textual content nothing else) and make user able to unlock them. So I'll need to add dynamic IAPs. Is there any possibility that Apple will reject my app for that?

Comment: I doubt they'd reject if all you're doing is download text resources into your app.